# What to do when I have new information on my own old question that never got a satisfactory answer?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919039/creating-a-custom-caption-bar-and-border-at-runtime-tmainmenu-acting-up) a few days ago and never got a satisfactory answer that suited  my needs. I now have new information, that might make it easier to answer the question.

How do I go about this? Should I edit the question and try to attract more traffic to it, or should I ask a new question and phrase it differently, so it's not an exact duplicate? (and possibly accept the answer I got on the original question, which was not a bad answer persé and did point me in the right direction?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases editing the question is exactly what you should do.

It will bump the question to the home page (if perhaps only briefly) and you'll get a fresh set of eyes on it.

If, however, the additional information would substantially change the question and/or invalidate any existing answers then you should really ask a new question. In this case it should be sufficiently different to the original so it shouldn't run the risk of being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Should I edit out information that's no longer very relevant? (at the risk of some comments and the one answer seeming a bit out of place) Should I maybe imply that big changes have been made to the question?

Comment: @overactor - If possible you should leave the original content in the post - otherwise it would make the original answer appear wrong.

Comment: That will make the question ridiculously long though.
If I edit the question, would it be okay to ask here for someone to take a look at it and tell me what needs to change about it?

Comment: @overactor - hmm, maybe leave a summary of the original content. Though the more you say the more it looks like you should be asking a new question.

Comment: I've made it a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020728/forcing-a-repaint-of-tmainmenu-when-handling-wm-ncpaint-yourself). Did I make the right decision and is it an okay question?